# RadCombobox doesnot maintain selected item

Tags: telerik, rad

I have binded RadCombo on LoadonDemand Event. when i change page of radgrid, RadCombo looses its selected item. 
How to maintain RadCombo selected item.
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `RadComboBox`'s `trackChanges()` and `commitChanges()` methods to preserve the selected item across post-backs?

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-radcombobox.html

I'm assuming the `RadGrid` is not contained in a `RadAjaxPanel` because if it were this would be taken care of automatically through partial page rendering (i.e. only the `RadGrid` would be re-rendered when paging occurs). It would probably be helpful if you could post you page's markup.

Answer (score 0):

When you page the grid is rebound and the controls inside it are recreated. To keep the combobox selection, save it Cache of Session object and then recover it from there wiring the PageIndexChanged event of the grid.

Comment: Combobox is not inside radgrid.